# Display multiple rows into one row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

Please see the example below:

[image]

I want to merge all these rows into a single row, note that the number of rows is dynamic!

The output should be like this:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: When you googled various clear statements of you question, what did you find? PS This is a faq, research "pivoting".

Comment: I didn't find the same example online !!

Comment: You will end up with dynamic column numbers and typically it is not at all usable. Also what order you want to show? Without providing order it will go for default storing order as in heap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = ''
Set @SQL = Stuff((Select Distinct ','  +QuoteName('C'+cast(RN as varchar(25))) 
                                   +','+QuoteName('P'+cast(RN as varchar(25)))
                   From (Select Distinct RN=Row_Number() over (Order By Pays) From YourTable) A  
                   Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 

Set @SQL = '
Select ' + replace(replace(@SQL,'[P','Pays=[P'),'[C','Count=[C') + '
From (
        Select B.*
         From  (
                Select *,RN = Row_Number() over (Order By Pays)
                 From  YourTable
               ) A
         Cross Apply (values (''P''+cast(A.RN as varchar(25)),A.Pays)
                            ,(''C''+cast(A.RN as varchar(25)),cast(A.Count as varchar(50)))
                     ) B (Item,Value)
     ) A
 Pivot (max(value) For [Item] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

**Returns**

[image]

---

**If it Helps, the Generated SQL Looks Like This:**

```
Select Count=[C1],Pays=[P1],Count=[C2],Pays=[P2],Count=[C3],Pays=[P3],Count=[C4],Pays=[P4]
From (
        Select B.*
         From  (
                Select *,RN = Row_Number() over (Order By Pays)
                 From  YourTable
               ) A
         Cross Apply (values ('P'+cast(A.RN as varchar(25)),A.Pays)
                            ,('C'+cast(A.RN as varchar(25)),cast(A.Count as varchar(50)))
                     ) B (Item,Value)
     ) A
 Pivot (max(value) For [Item] in ([C1],[P1],[C2],[P2],[C3],[P3],[C4],[P4]) ) p
```

Comment: @tollamie Happy it helped